# KitKat Animation and WebView rendering issue

Tags: android, webview, android-4.4-kitkat

I am facing a rendering issue when running animation to simple `View`. My setup has `ViewPager` and the first `Fragment` contains a `WebView` and the second `Fragment` has custom progress indicator which I animate.

Following image shows the problem, somehow there is relation with the `WebView` although the indicator is fully in it's own `Fragment`. My guess is that the platform uses the same GPU renderer and when having a `WebView` there it gets broken.

[image]

Anyone had same issue/found a workaround?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess was somewhat correct. I found a hack to fix this issue.

1. Extend `WebView` and override all constructors
2. Set layer type to software for the custom `WebView`

API level >= 11

```
setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```

API level < 11

```
try {
    Method setLayerType = getClass().getMethod("setLayerType",
            new Class[] { int.class, Paint.class });
    if (setLayerType != null)
        setLayerType.invoke(this, new Object[] { 1, null });
} catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
} catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
} catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
}
```

**NOTE:** This implementation dramatically affects performance of `WebView`.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this,

https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/migrating.html

In KitKat everything has pretty much changed.

Why don't you try and set the target SDK to 18. If you do this then the webview works in compatibility mode.